# Can't run first C program in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am an experienced smartphone programmer (android and IOS) but I am just getting started with Visual Studio Code on Mac OS 12. I have installed VScode, typed in a short "hello" program and attempted to run it.  I get an error about "a.out" not found and I'm asked to edit launch.json.  I have read the numerous solutions to this problem none of which worked however that may not be the real question.

Does VScode come with a C (or any other) compiler?  When installing I was asked to select extensions and installed gcc and clang.  I thought these might be compilers but now I think they aren't.  So...what are the best C compilers and how to do I install them to VScode and then how do I compile my code. I think the a.out error is probably looking for the compiled exe file.

Ahhhhh...is this the right place to ask this question? I couldn't find any VSc specific lists if there are any.

I typed in a brief "hello" program named FirstProg in C then selected "run without debugging".  I get a screen that says "launch:...FirstProg.exe does not exist. Launch.json".

I was expecting "hello" to appear somewhere.  It didn't

Comment: VS Code does not come with a C compiler. GCC and Clang are C compilers. Don't use SO Q&A to ask what compiler is "best"- not without giving more detail about what the context is. what you should do is read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp and the various linked resources- especially those about debugging.